# How can I list all files which have been installed by an ZYpp/Zypper package?

Tags: opensuse, zypper

How can I use `zypper` to list the locations of installed files for a given package?

Comment: Have you checked the man pages on zypper?

Comment: @ryekayo Yes, I have, but I haven't found what I want. I already tried `zypper info PACKAGE_NAME`, but doesn't list the installed files. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you also try searching online first? The first hit on on DuckDuckGo is: http://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/431424-zypper-list-files-in-package when using the terms "zypper list files in package"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In openSUSE, there are a few ways of listing installed files. With Zypper, I
would try:

```
zypper search -i
```

Or:

```
zypper search --installed-only
```

With RPM, you can try:

```
rpm -ql packageName | less
```

Comment: That lists the installed packages. What I need is the *list of files* installed by a package.

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: zypper suggestion still lists packages not installed files

Answer (score 23):

*rpm* can be used to list installed files from a package `<package>` with:

```
rpm -ql <package>
```

long version:

```
rpm --query --list <package>
```

zypper does (at the moment) not support listing installed files.

Also, I find the "reverse" helpful. To find the package "owning" a file `<file>` you can use

```
rpm -qf <file>
```

returning the exact package.

Answer (score 3):

As I cannot add comments, I'll add another answer and try to summarize it up properly, because the answers are nearly complete but scattered.

With *zypper* alone it is not possible, but as the package is installed by *zypper*, it is usually on your hard drive. If it is not on hard drive anymore, you can even just download it using *zypper*, without having to reinstall:

```
zypper in --download-only <package_name>
```

The package name that is downloaded is then shown. Usually, it is the last package name, because dependencies are retrieved first (e.g. *firewalld-0.7.5-1.1.noarch.rpm* for package *firewalld*). To find the directory you could simply use *find* like so:

```
find /var/cache/zypp -name <package_name>
```

It should return a single line with the full path to the file (e.g. */var/cache/zypp/packages/repo-oss/noarch/firewalld-0.7.5-1.1.noarch.rpm*). When you found the package and know its path, you can then use *rpm*:

```
rpm -ql <path_to_package>
```

What *rpm* then lists is the content of the package, including the paths where those files will be installed on your system or have already been installed on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but one other option is if you happen to be using openSUSE, there is a tab that shows the files installed by a package in the Yast2 Software Manager.

You can sort of get (some of) the files out of Zypper with this command:

```shell
zypper if --provides <packagename>
```

That lists what all you get with the package. Usually, not very elaborate, and doesn't include the libaries, but I don't know what your use case it, and it might be enough.

E.g.

```shellsession
~$  zypper if --provides util-linux
Loading repository data... Reading installed packages...
Information for package util-linux:
-----------------------------------
Repository     : openSUSE-Tumbleweed-Oss
Name           : util-linux
Version        : 2.39-3.1
Arch           : x86_64
Vendor         : openSUSE
Installed Size : 4.2 MiB
Installed      : Yes
Status         : out-of-date (version 2.39-2.1 installed)
Source package : util-linux-2.39-3.1.src
Upstream URL   : https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/
Summary        : A collection of basic system utilities (core part)
Description    :
    This package contains a large variety of low-level system utilities
    that are necessary for a Linux system to function. It contains the
    mount program, the fdisk configuration tool, and more.
Provides       : [27]
    /bin/su
    /bin/kill
    /bin/more
    /bin/mount
    /bin/umount
    util-linux(fake+no-canonicalize)
    config(util-linux) = 2.39-3.1
    eject = 2.1.0
    fsck-with-dev-lock = 2.39
    hardlink = 1.1
    login = 4.0
    rfkill = 0.5
    util-linux = 2.39-3.1
    util-linux(x86-64) = 2.39-3.1
    /usr/bin/getopt
    /usr/bin/ipcrm
    /usr/bin/ipcs
    /usr/bin/kill
    /usr/bin/more
    /usr/bin/mount
    /usr/bin/renice
    /usr/bin/setpriv
    /usr/bin/su
    /usr/bin/umount
    /usr/sbin/nologin
    /usr/bin/col
    /usr/sbin/agetty
```